# Improving the bound on the probability of censored waiting times

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

Suppose one observes a series of actions in time (say, user logins to a site). For each user, denote the time elapsed between logins as a random variable $T_{ik}$. Here $i$ denotes user for whom we have $k$ login time points.

So the average time elapsed between logins $E(T_i) = \mu_i$ will have some distribution over the set of users. Then, Markov's inequality tells us that:

$P(E(T_i) > t) \leq \frac{E(\mu_i)}{t}$

Suppose we want to filter out "extreme users". Define "extreme" as any user whose average time-between-logins has less than $p$ percent chance of occurring. Then the value of the critical threshold above which we will filter a given user as extreme will be:

$ p \leq \frac{E(\mu_i)}{t_c} \implies t_c \leq \frac{E(\mu_i)}{p}$

So if for any user $\mu_i > t_c$, we will filter them out as "extreme" (for a given value of $p$). Note further that we don't observe users until "death" (they may just be taking a really long time to long-in again, or they may have exited, we don't know).

I am wondering if there is a way to sharpen this bound, given the context of the problem.